# Javascript Regular Expression - Can't quite get it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to remove this from my query string: /page/2

Note: 2 could be any number.

So I am trying to remove a bracket, then the word page, then another bracket, and then a number.

This is what I have so far but I just can't quite get it:

```
str.replace(/\/page\/\[0-9]{1,}/, '');
```

Any pro out there knows what's wrong with this? Thanks.

Comment: Remove ``\`` before `[0-9`, it makes `[` be parsed as a literal `[` and ruins the character class. Is it a typo?

Comment: Oh dame! Your right, thanks that got it, and I was close Lol. No it wasn't a typo I am just new to regular expressions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct regex would be `/\/page\/[0-9]+/`.

In your regex you escaped the opening `[` which caused unexpected behaviour, I also replaced `{1,}` with `+` as it hase the same effect.

Comment: Yea that is correct. Thanks heaps for your help that worked! Will mark as the correct answer in 5 mins. Cheers.